# Easiest and quickest way of Web enabling old VBA apps

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

Given an small Excel VBA app (single form, small amount of records saved in single worksheet) that runs quite happily locally on the workstation, what would be the easiest and quickest way of providing the same app on the web?  Re-writing the app is an option but I thought it was worth checking if there was a quicker solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

If your business logic is fairly well-separated from the GUI code you could try wrapping it up as an OLE Automation object (called a COM object in VB6 I think) which you then use in an ASP-powered web application. The ASP part will be written in VBScript and use the COM object to do the calculations.

The problem here is that the usual VBA development style mingles GUI code and business logic together in the same subroutines and as a result teasing them apart and replacing the GUI with an ASP page will be more trouble than rewriting from scratch.

There is another way to write a web application using VB6 called Webclasses, but I do not recommend it.